# Multiple LTE connection bonding for live streaming

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming

I'm trying to build a device that does LTE connection bonding over multiple data plans for use in live streaming. It needs to be low latency but I'm willing to send duplicate packets/waste data. I want to use multiple data plans because with one I've found that coverage isn't super great and I do get some packet loss.

Note that because it needs to be low latency, failover/standard redundancy won't work for me.

Also given that it's for live streaming, portability is ideal. The architecture I'm imagining is:

[image: Architecture]

I've been looking up solutions and currently [LiveU](https://www.liveu.tv/) offers a commercial hardware + software solution and [Speedify](https://speedify.com/) offers just the software side of this but me being the enterprising hacker I am I'd like to figure out if there's open source tech that I can use to build this out and play with?

It seems that OpenWRT doesn't support anything like this as far as I can tell and I haven't found anything else promising. Would love to hear if anyone has any ideas for tools that might accomplish this.

Comment: With some more research, I've discovered [Multipath TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_TCP) and the [OpenMPTCP](https://www.openmptcprouter.com/) stack. I think this is what I'm looking for? Not 100% sure but it seems like it serves the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a few more hours of research, turns out the OpenMPTCP stack is what I'm looking for. There's a good [guide here](https://milankragujevic.com/openmptcprouter-true-bonding-of-2-wan-connections-for-cheap) if anyone finds this. I'm going to probably write a livestreaming specific guide too soon.

Comment: If you write a live-streaming guide for OpenMPTCP, posting a link here would be much appreciated. :-)